# SQL Server - Indexing and Operator precedence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having table Student as below

```
Student(id,jdate)
```

where column `id` is primary key. Now I'm writing a query as below

```
select * from Student where id=2 and (jdate='date1' or jdate='date2')
```

Will index work here? or Can i modify as below?

```
select * from Student where (id=2) and (jdate='date1' or jdate='date2')
```

Comment: To be 100% sure that query uses some index, you can use hint. After `from Student` add `WITH (INDEX (IX_YourIndexName))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your examples will use the PK Index for column 'id'.

In case it is not clear, The operator "=" has precedence over "and", and thus the parenthesis are not necessary.

Comment: yes, they are both the same as far as the SQL Server is concerned

Comment: operator "=" has precedence over "and", and thus the parenthesis are not necessary.

Comment: As you said, If i remove parenthesis on "id" then the other parenthesis"(jdate..)" will execute before "id=2". Isn't?

Comment: No, the other parenthesis"(jdate..)" will execute after id = 2, only for one time, for the row that is returned by the PK lookup

Comment: Ok. If "id" is not PK then the table will be filtered with "jdate" first. Am i correct?

Comment: I have checked, SQL Server does a FULL table scan to check the conditions. The order of the conditions is not important in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are declaring a PK on the id column then you are defining a unique clustered index on the table as well. And since you are using the id column in the where clause then the index should be used.

The two queries, both of them, will use the index and the parenthesis around id = 2 don't change anything in the logic / condition evaluation.

Comment: Unless otherwise specified, although the PK will also default as the Clustered index, this [behaviour can be overridden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051869/relationship-of-primary-key-and-clustered-index), and OP hasn't mentioned the choice of cluster key on the table.

Comment: @StuartLC, thanks for the linked info. It is an assumption that the PK on the table was created using the default behavior, with an UK clustered index "under the hood".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both queries will work and will both hit any relevant clustered or non clustered index.

Given that `id` is your table PK, you probably won't even hit any index on `jDate`. (i.e. although at first glance the index `(id, jdate)` seems useful, in practice it will be redundant given that `id` is the PK and queries targetting a single `id` will either use the `Clustered Index` (if the default PK clustering is used), or the `PK Constraint` itself (if the table has different clustering).

Although the spurious parenthesis around `id = 2` will be ignored, obviously `and` has precedence over `or`, so the parenthesis surrounding the `or` is essential:

```
... and (... or ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

As other users said - both queries are the same. And PK index will be used. If you have any doubts about which index is used (in this or other queries) see execution plan: (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Execution plan is a very useful tool. For example may prompt the missing indexes