# Primary key is different from clustered index

Tags: sql-server

Can we have primary key on one column and clustered index on another column ?

If so, what are the advantages and disadvantages on that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051869/relationship-of-primary-key-and-clustered-index/15053662#15053662

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. A primary key has to be unique and cannot contain nulls. A clustered index does not have to be unique. Usually (and by default when you create a primary key unless you explicitly say so) a primary key is by default a clustered index. To get a 'good' clustered index it is preferable that the index increase steadily (to minimize page splits) so often a clustered index is based on a column that is an identity column.